# C# Moved file without specifying path

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I just ran

`File.Move(@"C:\sub1\file.xml", "file" + ".XMl"));`

The file did dissappear from `C:\sub1`.  No error was thrown.  Did the file go somewhere?

Comment: to the current directory; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When directory is *not specified,* *current* one is used:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx

> The sourceFileName and destFileName arguments can include relative or
>   absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as
>   relative to the **current working directory**. To obtain the current
>   working directory, see [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
  Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\Test";

  // C:\sub1\file.xml will be moved to C:\Test\file.XMl 
  File.Move(@"C:\sub1\file.xml", "file" + ".XMl"));
```

Answer (score 3):

It moved to the app working directory. Usually it is where executable file located

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's in your running folder.